# ¿Cómo acceder a una posición de la fila en un datagridview?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Cuando tengo una rejilla cargada ¿cómo puedo obtener el valor de la segunda fila?

Comment: Hola, podrias agregar tu codigo? Tu pregunta no presenta ningun tipo de esfuerzo por lo que tendra que ser cerrada.

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega el codigo que actualmente tienes, asi recibiras una mejor respuesta por parte de la comunidad

Answer (score 1):

podrias utilizar

```
int rowIndex = 1;

DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
```

recuerda que en las colecciones los indices comienzan en cero, por eso la segunda fila es la 1

si quieres acceder a una columna concreta usarias

```
string cellValue = row.Cells["nombreCol"].Value.ToString();
```

puede acceder indicando el nombre de la columna

---

Si la idea es tomar el dato de una columna iterando las rows usarias

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows){

  string cellValue = row.Cells["nombreSegundaCol"].Value.ToString();

}
```

Comment: entiendo Leandro, seria asi? DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];?

Comment: Si, en adición, si quieres acceder a la fila que tiene el foco, defines así: `DataGridViewRow row = DataGridView1.CurrentRow;`

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dgvDetalle.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
  //aqui quiero leer y obtener el valor de la 2da fila
 }

Comment: ¿Será la segunda columna? Edita la pregunta y agrega lo que has intentado.

Comment: disculpa, si es con rowIndex, edite la respuesta agregando un ejemplo adicional